# How do I get system boot time in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I need the System Boot Time in a batch script, only the time, no date, no string.
I can't get it into a variable

```
set systime=systeminfo | find "System Boot Time"
echo %systime%
```

The only thing, which is working, is:

```
systeminfo | find "System Boot Time">>c:\time.txt
```

I need it as batch because I need to modify an already existing batchfile.

Edit:
Changed “System Boot Time” to "System Boot Time" dont know where these come from ^^

Comment: Take a look at the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), which is capable of capturing the output of a command... By the way, don't use typographical quotes `“”`, use straight ones only `""`!

Answer (score 1):

I would use WMI to get just the information I required, instead of running SystemInfo, and parsing out what I needed.

```bat
For /F EOL^=L %%A In ('WMIC OS Get LastBootUpTime 2^>Nul')Do For %%B In (%%~nA)Do Set "SBT=%%B"&Call Set "SBT=%%SBT:~-6,2%%:%%SBT:~-4,2%%:%%SBT:~-2%%"
Echo(%SBT%
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following lines in nodepad and save as .cmd extension.

```
@ECHO OFF
systeminfo | find "System Boot Time"
PAUSE
```